# Polish Opening development

Tags: opening, development

The main idea of this opening is to get a mass of center pawns, for less development. How can White get his pieces out before Black can develop too many pieces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line that you refer to is probably 1.b4 e5 2.Bb2 Bxb4 3. Bxe5 Nf6.. I recall some early opening books saying that this was a bad defence because it surrendered a center pawn. The more modern view is that Black does get a very fast development in this line which is quite dangerous. I gave up the Polish when this started to become well-known. Until then I had good results. Often I got something like a reversed Sicilian with a very useful move thrown in.

I have not kept up with recent developments but there is an article in New in Chess
yearbook 132(2019) which is where I would go to catch up.